# Mysql GROUP BY column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a table

```
+---------+----------+------------+---------------------+
| user_id | campaign | event_type | date                |
+---------+----------+------------+---------------------+
|       1 | MobiKwik | install    | 2015-03-14 09:56:33 |
|       2 | MobiKwik | install    | 2015-03-14 09:56:33 |
|       3 | Micromax | click      | 2015-03-14 09:56:33 |
|       4 | Quickr   | click      | 2015-03-14 09:56:33 |
|       5 | Quickr   | install    | 2015-03-14 09:56:33 |
|       6 | MobiKwik | click      | 2015-03-14 09:56:33 |
|       7 | Amazon   | install    | 2015-03-14 09:56:33 |
|       8 | MobiKwik | click      | 2015-03-14 09:56:33 |
|       1 | MobiKwik | install    | 2015-03-14 10:49:32 |
|       2 | MobiKwik | install    | 2015-03-14 10:49:32 |
|       3 | Micromax | click      | 2015-03-14 10:49:32 |
|       4 | Quickr   | click      | 2015-03-14 10:49:32 |
|       5 | Quickr   | install    | 2015-03-14 10:49:32 |
|       6 | MobiKwik | click      | 2015-03-14 10:49:32 |
|       7 | Amazon   | install    | 2015-03-14 10:49:32 |
|       8 | MobiKwik | click      | 2015-03-14 10:49:32 |
+---------+----------+------------+---------------------+
```

I want to write a query that will be group the results in following manner,

```
Campaign InstallCount ClickCount
Amazon      2           0
Mobikwik    4           4
micromax    0           2
and so on.
```

**How can I write such a query?**

Here's what I tried!!

```
select * from tablename group by campaign,even_type;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL you can do

```
select campaign, 
       sum(even_type = 'install') as InstallCount,
       sum(even_type = 'click') as ClickCount
from tablename 
group by campaign
```

and ANSI SQL standard is

```
select campaign, 
       sum(case when even_type = 'install' then 1 else 0 end) as InstallCount,
       sum(case when even_type = 'click' then 1 else 0 end) as ClickCount
from tablename 
group by campaign
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than 5 itens in campaign, is better to do this:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;

SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(case when tablename_.event_type = ''',
      event_type,
      ''' then 1 else 0 end)',
      event_type
    )
   )INTO @sql
FROM tablename_; 


SET @sql=CONCAT('SELECT campaign, ',@sql,' FROM tablename_ GROUP BY tablename_.campaign');



PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The codebase is from juergen d.